# Dropzonejs doesnt attach files to form

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzonejs to take care of file uploads. I have a large form and files are only part of it. I have attached dropzone to div inside a form, but files are appended to the end of body. Is there a way to get files inside form so they would be send with rest of the data?

Comment: Could you please provide what your form and JS code look like?

Comment: check if this could help you https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion (what i did) : I have two forms - one that has the dropzone and uploads the files to the server and another form that takes in the other details. When the form with the other details is submitted, i make a call to a javascript function that apart from handling the data that is submitted, also gets all the files that were uploaded via the dropzone form ; something like -

```
var uploadedFiles[] = myDropZoneForm.getAcceptedFiles();
```

Then all this data (including the files) is packaged and sent to the server for further handling. 
Hope that helps.